# Having issue in reuseable cell in UITableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, reuseidentifier

I have two kinds of design in single `UITableViewCell`. Here is the design which I want and getting at the time of loading viewController

[image: Correct cell design]
But after scrolling I'm getting following result.
[image: InCorrect design]

I think this problem is caused by reusability of UITableViewCell. here is my code of cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "notificationCell", for: indexPath) as! NotificationTableViewCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.btnClose.tag = indexPath.row
        let noti_flag = (arrayNotificationList.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "noti_flag") //as! String
         let noti_flag_string = NSString(format: "%@", noti_flag as! CVarArg) as String

        cell.lbl_From.text = (arrayNotificationList.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "caller_id") as? String ?? ""

        if noti_flag_string == "0" {
            cell.lblTime.isHidden = true
            cell.imgThumbIcon.isHidden = true
            cell.lbl_remaining.isHidden = true
            cell.lbl_mm_text.text = "Missed call"
            cell.lbl_mm_text.font = cell.lbl_mm_text.font.withSize(23)

        }
        else{

            var startAttributedText = (arrayNotificationList.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "rebound_start_time") as! String
            var endAttributedText = (arrayNotificationList.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "rebound_end_time") as! String
            startAttributedText = Model.shared.convertLocalTimeToServer(timeString: startAttributedText,isTimeFromServer: true)
            endAttributedText = Model.shared.convertLocalTimeToServer(timeString: endAttributedText,isTimeFromServer: true)
            let dateString:String = startAttributedText + " - " + endAttributedText

            cell.lblTime.attributedText = convertStringToAttr(dateString: dateString)

            cell.lbl_remaining.text = (arrayNotificationList.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "remaining_time") as? String ?? ""

            cell.lbl_mm_text.text = (arrayNotificationList.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "mm_text") as? String ?? ""

            //cell.lbl_From.text = (arrayNotificationList.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "caller_id") as? String ?? ""

            let mm_type = (arrayNotificationList.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "mm_type") as! String//"img"
            switch mm_type {
            case "img":
                cell.imgThumbIcon.image = UIImage(named: "thumb_camera")
            case "vid":
                cell.imgThumbIcon.image = UIImage(named: "thumb_video")
            case "aud":
                cell.imgThumbIcon.image = UIImage(named: "thumb_audio")
            case "str":
                cell.imgThumbIcon.image = UIImage(named: "thumb_sticker")
            case "txt":
                cell.imgThumbIcon.image = UIImage(named: "thumb_text")
            case "brd":
                cell.imgThumbIcon.image = UIImage(named: "thumb_brand")
            default:
                cell.imgThumbIcon.image = UIImage(named: "thumb_camera")
            }
        }


        return cell
    }
```

So please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think issue in `arrayNotificationList `. Please debug and check your array values.

Comment: @nirav you can use two cell easily manage.

Comment: `cell.lblTime.isHidden = true` you don't do `cell.lblTime.isHidden = false` in the else case. Each time you modify a property, think about what to do in the other case : hide/show/change value, etc. Else, you can override `prepareForReuse()` to do that, and hide/show/reset value.

Comment: Many many Thanks @Larme. It's help me a lot.

Comment: Please post this as answer so I can mark as accepted.@Larme

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you scrolled, the

```
        cell.lblTime.isHidden = true
```

line hid the label in the cell. When it was reused, it was still hidden so the middle label enlarged to fill up the remaining space.

The solution is to either,

A. Create another cell subclass which cleans up the code considerably and it would no longer be necessary to show or hide labels.

B. Make sure to set

```
cell.lblTime.isHidden = false
```

in the else clause.

I hope this helps.